# Chrome extension disable app if same app was installed already

Tags: web, browser, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Im working on a chrome extension that has been released as several versions
for several brands. Actually they have the same handling but its like a different app. How can I prohibit double installations ? So for instance if App A is installed disable App B on installation or just disable it in general.

Comment: First you need to clarify if it's an [app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) or an [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Extensions can use [chrome.management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) to disable/uninstall themselves or other extensions.

Comment: Well then its an extension